# MvvmCross Network Plugin WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am working on an mvvmcross solution. I am making a wpf project as well to speed up the core development. Today I ran into an issue running a wpf project using a core that has the network plugin. When the setup.Initialize() is called I end up with the exception "Could not load file or assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Wpf' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.". I did include the network plugin from NuGet to my wpf project as well. Anyone know what might be the issue here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i only added the wpf version of that plugin 5 days ago - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commits/TibetBinding/Plugins/Cirrious/Network/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Network.Wpf

It hasn't yet made it to nuget - when it will depends on my work schedule and my hotel wifi - 'soon' is all I can say.

You can build it for yourself if you need it urgently - on the tibetbinding branch (see link above)

Comment: Stuart you rock! Thank you very much for this amazing framework and for such a quick response :)

Comment: @stuart Is there a sqllite plugin for wpf on the horizon?

Comment: Yes, please see the link in the answer